# Handling HTTP request arguments in a PHP script

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, http, asihttprequest

In an Objective-C method I use this

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxxxxx.com/test/test.php?id=3333&vote=1"];    
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

How do I write a PHP script to receive those two arguments and pass them into local variables? In the end I would imagine something like `$id` and `$vote` which would equal `3333` and `1` respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how it's done :

```
<?php

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $vote = $_GET['vote'];

    //do processing here
```

but make sure you do some SQL injection proofing before inserting those values into a database

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET['id']` will hold URL arguments, `$_POST['id']` analog for form elements

You should NOT use `$_REQUEST`, best of all you know where your user input comes from, so use `$_GET` if you expect GET requests, and `$_POST` for form processing.
(Same for `$_COOKIE` and `$_SESSION`).

Answer (score 0):

You can get those values using

```
<?php

$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$vote = $_REQUEST['vote'];
?>
```

Comment: This is a bit of bad form as the `$_REQUEST` variable is made from any of `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_COOKIE`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$vote = $_GET['vote'];
```